# how to switch between vs 2008 & IE (web page) after making changes in code written in vs 2008?

Tags: c#, asp.net, keyboard-shortcuts

I am new to the .NET environment. I have not used vs 2008 much more times. I just started to develop some asp.net pages. I can develop asp.net pages & then use the menu bar in vs 2008 to start debugging. When I start debugging the asp.net web page gets displayed in IE. I want to know the trick by which we can make changes in our existing code in vs 2008 & then go to the IE & refresh our page & our pages should be displayed with the changes done without debugging every time. Is there any way to do this ? If there is any shortcut key then can you please tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the HTML in your aspx page and click save, then click <kbd>F5</kbd> (or Refresh) in your browser to reload your web page (with your changes).

**Edit:** Also see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcew296c(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> ("Start without Debugging"). This should start your ASP.NET development server (was installed when you installed VS). Then reload the page in IE.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the debugger, it should load the cassini server and attach the debugger. If you stop debugging, the cassini server does not stop running. You should be able to continue to refresh the page even after you've stopped debugging.

If, for some reason, your cassini server is dropping, you can also set up your local IIS website for localhost to point to the directory where your website is, and then you could load it like any other website simply with http://localhost/.

Also, if you're developing a website instead of a web application project, you can make changes to the aspx and code behind files without stopping the debugger. Simply saving and refreshing after you make your changes should cause the page to recompile itself on demand and display what you want.

Comment: Might help to point out to a newbie that Cassini = ASP.NET Development Server.

Comment: @Brett:  I didn't know that either, and I've been doing it for a few years.

Comment: Yeah, the 'Cassini' is/was Microsoft's codename for what became the ASP.Net Development Server.  Handy to know when someone throws that into a conversation!! (More here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_codename)

Comment: @Brett Rigby, @recursive - Apologies. I took this for common knowledge. It is used conversationally where I work, and I didn't think about it being not commonly used.

Comment: Ha ha, I didn't mean anything by it! I only added it to clear-up any potential confusion, that's all.  But you're right, we refer to it at work as Cassini too - ASP.Net Development Server is a bit of a mouthful!! :o)